# nodejs sequlize where condition id notequal to check in

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have updated the brand details in the updateBrand function. When updating the details, i have checked the duplication of name and not checked in same id.

(i.e) select * from "brand" where brand_name = $brand_name AND id <> $bid;

In the nodejs i wrote

```
let duplicateData = await Brand.findOne({ where:searchQuery});
```

Please tell how can we use the "<>"(not equal to) in nodejs sequelize query.

brandcontroller.js

```
updateBrand: async (request, h) => {
  try {
    let bid = request.query.id;
    let searchQuery = {};
    searchQuery.id = bid;
    let {
      brand_name,
      brand_image,
      description,
      colorshead,
      colorsbg,
      brand_id,
      status,
      activedate,
      expirydate,
    } = request.payload;
    ///check name already exists
    searchQuery.brand_name = brand_name;
    let duplicateData = await Brand.findOne({ where: searchQuery });
    if (!duplicateData) {
      let updateBrand = await Brand.update(
        {
          brand_name: brand_name,
          brand_image: brand_image,
          colorshead: colorshead,
          colorsbg: colorsbg,
          brand_id: brand_id,
        },
        {
          where: {
            id: bid,
          },
        },
      );
      let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        message: message.DATAFOUND,
      };
      return h.response(response).code(200);
    } else {
      return Boom.badRequest(message.NAMEEXISTS);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Boom.badRequest(err.message);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$ne` for `<>` :

```
where: {
    id: { $ne : bid },
}
```

For more **[Operators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)**

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Doshi. Its working. let duplicateData = await Product.findOne({ where: {
                                id: { $ne : bid },
                                product_name : product_name
                                }});